# =, BINARY, LIKE, LIKE BINARY, REGEXP, agrupamento binário SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, desempenho

Reformulação da pergunta a partir da resposta do @GabrielHenrique e pesquisa:

O que é agrupamento binário em uma coluna string na tabela?

`BINARY` serve para fazer uma busca case-sensitive e `LIKE` case-insensitive, então `LIKE BINARY` seria uma comparação case-sensitive com o uso do `%` e `_` para completar o texto com qualquer valor?

Tem diferença e o que é mais performático, `BINARY` ou apenas `=`? Essa diferença é significativa em tabelas grandes? E em tabelas pequenas?

Qual é mais performático, `REGEXP` ou `LIKE`? Essa diferença é significativa em tabelas grandes? E em tabelas pequenas?

Qual é mais performático, `REGEXP` ou `LIKE BINARY`? Essa diferença é significativa em tabelas grandes? E em tabelas pequenas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Segundo a documentação do MySQL ([string comparation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-comparison-functions.html)), as comparações de strings não são *case-sensitive*, a menos que um dos operadores 
seja *case-sensitive*, ou o *collation* do campo seja.

Portanto, usar `=` ou `LIKE` também pode ser uma busca *case-sensitive* dependendo do *collation*, assim por exemplo:

```
 LIKE _latin1 'ABC%' COLLATE latin1_bin
```

Usando `LIKE BINARY` força uma comparação binária independente do *collation*,  garantindo a comparação *case-sensitive*, embora possa prejudicar a performance dependendo do tamanho da tabela.

Sobre o uso de `REGEX` vs `LIKE`, algumas considerações devem ser feitas:
`REGEX` não utiliza um índice, mesmo que presente, o que irá impactar na performance;
`LIKE` usa um índice, se houver, desde que não inicie a comparação por `%` ou `'_'`;

Aqui tem uma excelente resposta no SO inglês sobre isso:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/8431675/4730201

**EDIT**: por sugestão estou copiando uma parte interessante da resposta do link acima:

```
SELECT * FROM t WHERE a = 'abc'      <<-- (case insensitive ) pode usar o índice se existir
SELECT * FROM t WHERE a LIKE 'abc'   <<-- (case insensitive como "=") pode usar o índice se existir
SELECT * FROM t WHERE a LIKE 'abc%'  <<-- pode usar o índice se existir
SELECT * FROM t WHERE a LIKE 'a%'    <<-- pode usar o índice se existir, dependendo da cardinalidade (1)
SELECT * FROM t WHERE a LIKE '%a%'   <<-- não vai usar um índice
SELECT * FROM t WHERE a LIKE '_agf'  <<-- não vai usar um índice
```

**(1)** Segundo o autor da resposta, dependendo da cardinalidade o MySQL pode ou não usar um índice:
Se mais de +/- 20% das linhas corresponderem ao critério, o MySQL não usará um índice, porque, nesse caso, fazer uma busca completa "*full table scan*" da tabela é mais rápido

Portanto, do ponto de vista de performance, é interessante considerar a presença de um índice na coluna, o *collation* e a pesquisa que será feita (iniciado ou não por `%` ou `_`) para escolher a melhor forma de comparação.

Dependendo também da comparação frequente no campo, iniciando por `%` e do volume de dados, uma outra opção a ser considerada é o uso de um índice *fulltext*, que é próprio pra otimizar esse tipo de pesquisa. Mais informação (em inglês) aqui: [MySQL Fulltext Index](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/fulltext-search.html)

**EDIT**: esclarecendo uma dúvida sobre o `COLLATION`:
No exemplo acima, da documentação do MySQL, ele está especificando o collation que deseja usar na comparação, independente do `collation` original.
Como exemplo, uma tabela com um campo que foi criado assim `texto VARCHAR(50) CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_german1_ci`, ou seja a coluna nome está com o collation em alemão, mas você deseja comparar usando espanhol, você poderia fazer assim: `WHERE texto LIKE _latin1 'ABC%' COLLATE latin1_spanish_ci`

Coloquei um exemplo aqui: [sqlfiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c11845/4)

Comment: Poderia explicar as partes desse SQL: `LIKE _latin1 'ABC%' COLLATE latin1_bin`? Se puder adicionar a pergunta as partes mais relevantes com um exmplo (em portugues) dos links que colocou, agradeço

Comment: Olá @GuilhermeCostamilam, nesse exemplo da documentação do `MySQL`,  ele está especificando o *collation* que quer comparar, independente do *collation* original. Imagina que tem uma tabela com um campo que foi criado assim `texto VARCHAR(50) CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_german1_ci`, ou seja a coluna nome está com o *collation* em alemão, mas você deseja comparar usando espanhol, você poderia fazer assim: `where texto LIKE _latin1 'ABC%' COLLATE latin1_spanish_ci` entendeu?
Vou colocar na resposta

Comment: Boa resposta e exemplo, só faltou `BINARY` vs `=` e talvez desenvolver um pouco mais sobre os índices. Obrigado

Comment: boa, amanhã vou editar com algumas informações, obrigado pelas dicas

Answer (score 9):

No MySQL, **BINARY** tem a função de forçar uma comparação exata, ou seja, uma comparação case-sensitive, byte a byte.

Creio que a utilização deste agrupamento seja para otimização da busca quando se busca um valor em especifíco.